# Gutenberg withAPIData HOC not fetching on page reload

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Followed this [example](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/blocks/creating-dynamic-blocks/) from Gutenberg handbook

It's fetching post normally on block add. But after saving and reloading post edit page there is no data and stuck in 'loading' state

```
{get: ƒ, isLoading: true, path: "/wp/v2/posts?per_page=4", create: ƒ, isCreating: false}
```

Comment: Same issue here. Could reproduce this. Only when a block is added, the request fills the data property. Even tough the original request gets finished with status code 200.

Comment: For reference: I've added an issue on Github: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/6537